# Porque en localhost no puedo insertar datos a mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, localhost

Estoy intentando insertar datos en la base de datos pero no inserta nada!

```
$new = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO vpv_items_list(`list_sku`, `list_name_item`, `list_price`, `list_cant`, `list_total`, `list_session`) VALUES ('".$rows['item_sku']."', '".$rows['item_name']."', '".$rows['item_price']."', '".$cant."', '".$total."', '".$code."') ");
```

Solo me inserta cuando agrego las demas columnas!

```
 $new = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO vpv_items_list(`list_sku`, `list_name_item`, `list_price`, `list_cant`, `list_total`, `list_session`, `list_payme_success`, `list_free_tax`, `list_points`, `list_cr_buy`) VALUES ('".$rows['item_sku']."', '".$rows['item_name']."', '".$rows['item_price']."', '".$cant."', '".$total."', '".$code."', '', '', '', '') ");
```

ayuda por favor! porque solo asi puedo insertar, pero ya en codigo mas largo no puedo!

Comment: Puede que alguna(s) de las columna(s) que omites no acepten un valor `NULL` por defecto que es lo que se estaría intentando  insertar en ese caso. Lo puedes verificar capturando los errores en tu código, de hecho, deberías programar siempre de ese modo si quieres escribir un código robusto.

Comment: Oh, entiendo, y como puedo hacer que acepten NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

Puede que alguna(s) de las columna(s) que omites no acepten un valor `NULL` por defecto que es lo que se estaría intentando  insertar en ese caso. Lo puedes verificar capturando los errores en tu código, de hecho, deberías programar siempre de ese modo si quieres escribir un código robusto.

Por ejemplo:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO vpv_items_list(
    `list_sku`, 
    `list_name_item`, 
    `list_price`, 
    `list_cant`, 
    `list_total`, 
    `list_session`) 
VALUES (
    '$rows[item_sku]', 
    '$rows[item_name]', 
    '$rows[item_price]', 
    '$cant', 
    '$total', 
    '$code')";

if( $new = $mysqli->query($sql) ) {
    $outPut=sprintf("Se insertaron %d filas",$mysqli->affected_rows);
} else {
    #Considera cambiar $mysqli->error por un mensaje personalizado en producción
    $outPut=sprintf("Ocurrió un error: %s",$mysqli->error);
}
echo $outPut;
```

Comment: oh entiendo! Muchas gracias, lo puedo aplicar igual para el UPDATE ?

Comment: ¿Aplicar qué cosa en concreto? En cuanto a que acepte `NULL` debes indicarlo en la definición de la tabla, @AbelardoCM.

Comment: Si, eso mereferia  aplicarlo a la tabla!, creo que no me exprese bien, gracias!

Comment: @AbelardoCM pues eso, para que acepte `NULL` tienes que indicarlo en la definición de la tabla, sea al crearla inicialmente, sea mediante un `ALTER TABLE` si la tabla ya existe y tiene datos.